# Sony SmartWatch 3 (SWR50) no longer returns Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

I am writing an application which uses the Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION.

```
mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION);
```

This was working up until recently however each SensorEvent now returns a values float array containing: NaN, NaN, NaN.

I have tried the same code on an LG watch and it is returning values as I would expect.

The versions of software on the SWR50 are:

Android Wear 1.1.1.1929530

Google Play services 7.5.71 (1955121-534)

Android OS 5.1.1

Note that the Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER returns values (which was confirmed in the Manufacturer (Menu-Launcher) app in the developer options) so the accelerometer doesn't appear to be broken.

Can anyone from Sony confirm this issue? Otherwise maybe I need to get a new watch if it is broken.

Comment: I am also getting NANs (and no actual values) from TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION.

Android Wear 1.3.0.2160025

Google Play services 8.4.89 (2428711-534)

Android OS 5.1.1

After I reboot the watch it seems to work OK - but every time I run the app after that I only get NaNs back.

Comment: I started facing the same issue today after upgrading sony-smartwatch-3 to 6.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds strange that it would just stop working all of a sudden.

1. Did you install any firmware updates recently?
2. Have you tried power cycling the watch?
3. Have you tried doing a factory reset?

Comment: 1. Yes the update to 5.1.1 during I|O.
2. Yes; that seems to have worked, although I'm still getting some NaNs.

Comment: This issue is still there after 6.0.1 upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like the Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY is the issue. It returns valid results after a reboot and then the next time I run the app it returns NaNs. Presumably LINEAR_ACCELERATION is using the gravity vector to calculate this.

If I had to guess I would say some spurious value is being put into the low pass filter that is calculating the gravity vector and once that happens it will never recover.

I guess if it is a random value that is being added then occasionally it might be valid which is why occasionally it seems to work.

I guess the work-around is to read the Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER values instead and do the low pass filtering to work out gravity.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded my Sony smart-watch-3 SWR50 firmware to following and my application is no more getting callbacks from Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION.

Android Wear 1.4.0.2715035

Google Play services 8.7.02 (2624717-534)

Android OS 6.0.1

Build Number: MEC24H

Comment: I'm getting the same issue - did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: It has been a long time. I don't really remember how I resolved it. But most likely a newer version of firmware might have fixed it.