# Software sensors in sony smartwatch 3

Tags: android, wear-os, android-sensors, sony-smartwatch

We are using the  `TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION` `TYPE_GRAVITY` sensor event values for our wearable application but for sony smartwatch 3 our app cannot provide compatibility because of the lack of these two sensor

the official docs says

> The Android Open Source Project (AOSP) provides three software-based
>   motion sensors: a gravity sensor, a linear acceleration sensor, and a
>   rotation vector sensor. These sensors were updated in Android 4.0 and
>   now use a device's gyroscope (in addition to other sensors) to improve
>   stability and performance. If you want to try these sensors, you can
>   identify them by using the getVendor() method and the getVersion()
>   method (the vendor is Google Inc.; the version number is 3).
>   Identifying these sensors by vendor and version number is necessary
>   because the Android system considers these three sensors to be
>   secondary sensors. For example, if a device manufacturer provides
>   their own gravity sensor, then the AOSP gravity sensor shows up as a
>   secondary gravity sensor. All three of these sensors rely on a
>   gyroscope: if a device does not have a gyroscope, these sensors do not
>   show up and are not available for use.

So my question is if the OEM doesn't provide the primary support for these three soft based sensor then is there a way of using the AOSP one. i didn't understand how to use them as mentioned in the docs it just says to use getVendor() getversion() it only checks who is the vendor and what is the version.
Other approach would be using of filters for getting these gravity and linear acceleration values from gyroscope values but i dont know how exactly to do that and what are the caveats of using it.

PS. LG G WATCH and Moto 360 do provide these sensor,also i checked the vendor from the getVendor method its EM Micro for Sony and Invensense for G watch. no Google Inc in G watch also

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this question [Sony SmartWatch 3 (SWR50) no longer returns Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855269/sony-smartwatch-3-swr50-no-longer-returns-sensor-type-linear-acceleration/37311164#37311164)

For some reason the 'Linear acceleration' and 'gravity' sensor aren't working properly on sony smart-watch 3. You can use accelerometer sensor to get the acceleration, apply the low-pass filter to get the Gravity values and substract the gravity values to get 'linear acceleration'. Please refer the code sample below.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){
  // In this example, alpha is calculated as t / (t + dT),
  // where t is the low-pass filter's time-constant and
  // dT is the event delivery rate.

  final float alpha = 0.8;

  // Isolate the force of gravity with the low-pass filter.
  gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
  gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
  gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];

  // Remove the gravity contribution with the high-pass filter.
  linear_acceleration[0] = event.values[0] - gravity[0];
  linear_acceleration[1] = event.values[1] - gravity[1];
  linear_acceleration[2] = event.values[2] - gravity[2];
}
```